# Dealing with null values in PSCustomObject from sql table..Unable to cast object

Tags: sql, powershell

In pulling data from SQL, some of the columns in the row are null. I receive an exception message:

> Exception calling "GetString" with "1" argument(s): "Unable to cast
>   object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'."

How can I handle this? It seems to basically just move on to the next row, but I need all rows and all columns. If the column is null, ok with me but I do need to set it as an empty string, I guess. This data will be used to set details for users in AD. When I use the `Set-ADUser` command, I will need to be able to use the variable even if it is null. I don't want PowerShell to not execute the `Set-ADUser` command because the particular variable is empty. The one it fails on the most is the supr_username.

It took me a long time to get the output from the Oracle sql table so that I could use it for `Set-ADUser`. I have not found anything as yet to do what I am trying to do.

`````
 [pscustomobject]@{
 Identity = $_.GetString(2)
 Title = $_.GetString(3)
 Department = $_.GetString(4)
 MSC = $_.GetString(5)
 Office_Location = $_.GetString(6)
 Office_Phone = $_.GetString(7)
 Supr_username = $_.GetString(10)
 }
 }````
`````

Comment: How many users are we talking about here? If it's not a huge number you could store the output from the database in a list, and do an if-statement before running Set-ADUser replacing any null values with something else. Exactly how I'd do it in this case is hard to say without seeing more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your custom object properties with values of empty string (`""`). Then you can test if the column index (ordinal) contains a `DBNull` and convert to string if it is not `DBNULL`.

```
$obj = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{Identity = ""
    Title = ""
    Department = ""
    MSC = ""
    Office_Location = ""
    Office_Phone = ""
    Supr_username = ""
    }

$obj.Identity = if (!$_.isDbNull(2)) { $_.GetString(2) }
$obj.Title = if (!$_.isDbNull(3)) { $_.GetString(3) }
$obj.Department = if (!$_.isDbNull(4)) { $_.GetString(4) }
$obj.MSC = if (!$_.isDbNull(5)) { $_.GetString(5) }
$obj.Office_Location = if (!$_.isDbNull(6)) { $_.GetString(6) }
$obj.Office_Phone = if (!$_.isDbNull(7)) { $_.GetString(7) }
$obj.Supr_username = if (!$_.isDbNull(10)) { $_.GetString(10) }

$obj
```

Comment: Thanks!I ended up doing this while reading the table (before I saw your post): if ($SelectDataTable.IsDBNUll(2)) {$Identity = "none"} else {$Identity = $SelectDataTable.GetString(2)} .... After going through the variables I run a set-aduser... I think I have about 1000 users. Is doing it my way efficient? I guess I'll measure it. I want to put the code in here but not enough room as a comment?

Comment: @bvi1998 I don't think your way is any less efficient than mine.